# Outbound email IS working but warning Outbound Email Disabled is still shown

Tags: email, backdrop, outbound-email

I have a civiCRM install (v. 5.67.3) working fine with backdrop (v. 1.26.2), emails are being sent, also the test mail on the SMTP config screen, but there is still a warning message, on civiCRM status page, about outbound email being disabled:

```
Warning: Outbound email is disabled in system settings. Proper settings should be enabled on production servers.
```

I cannot see where the problem is. Any clues? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to administer - system settings - outbound mail, what does it have there? And when you say "emails are being sent", are they actually being received?

Note also it's possible to override what's on that admin screen with a setting in civicrm.settings.php, so if that screen gives a popup about it being overridden, check in the settings file.

Comment: Yes, emails are being sent and received. civicrm settings do not override any setting on that admin screen. However, I set a mail.log file by defining "CIVICRM_MAIL_LOG". That log file is being created and populated normally. I found out that unsetting CIVICRM_MAIL_LOG that warning disappears... why?

Answer (score 0):

Unsetting CIVICRM_MAIL_LOG on civicrm.settings.php gets rid of the warning, but I lose my logs, of course, which were, BTW, working fine (the file was being populated with new entries for each sent email). Does this make any sense??

Comment: Yes that setting will disable sending mail for real. If you want to log and send there is CIVICRM_MAIL_LOG_AND_SEND - see https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/debugging/#changing-file-based-settings